# Get an element at a specific index from a NavigableSet

Tags: java, collections, set, median

I have a `NavigableSet` and I would like to get its median object.

Being that it's a `NavigableSet`, I know it's sorted, and thus I know that the median of it is either the middle element, or the arithmetic middle of the two middle elements.

Therefore I would like to access the element at `set.size() / 2`, but the `NavigableSet` interface doesn't allow me to.

Is there an easy way to get the specific element without having to iterate through the set manually?

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of NavigableSet you're working with, but if update time is not critical, you can construct one backed by a sorted array, and then it's trivial to find the median.

Answer (score 0):

Yes set does not allow you to get an element from a particular index. But I think if you convert it to an array then you will be able to achieve what you need. I tried this sample code, see if it helps:

```
NavigableSet set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
set.add(new Integer(5));
set.add(new Integer(4));
set.add(new Integer(3));
set.add(new Integer(2));
set.add(new Integer(1));
Integer medianIndex = set.size()/2;
System.out.println(set.toArray()[medianIndex]);
```

> Output: 3

Comment: Converting it to an array is a more expensive operation than iterating through it, so I wouldn't choose this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are ordered alphabetically, have a look at this small example:

Edit: Now it really does what you wanted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
    set.add("gamma");
    set.add("alpha");
    set.add("beta");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));

    int indexOfGamma = set.headSet("gamma").size();

    System.out.println(indexOfGamma);

    System.out.println(get(set, set.first(), indexOfGamma));
}

public static String get(NavigableSet<String> set, String e, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        return e;
    }
    return get(set, set.higher(e), --index);
}
```

This is the output:

```
[alpha, beta, gamma]
2
gamma
```

I didn't do any benchmarks with greater data-sets, but I guess it should perform quite decent. The `higher()` method should directly point to the next element in the tree.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this has anything to do with my question.

Comment: You are right, what I suggested is just the other way around: Finding the index to a certain object in the set. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any way other than iterating through the set "index" number of times. However, since we know the size of the set, we can speed that up to at least half the size by using both ascending and descending iteration:

```
public static <T> T getInNavigableSetByIndex(NavigableSet<T> set, int index) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(set);

    final int size = set.size();

    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    final boolean descend = index >= size / 2;
    final Iterator<T> itr = descend ? set.descendingIterator() : set.iterator();
    final int stepCount = descend ? size - index : index + 1;
    T object = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < stepCount && itr.hasNext(); i++) {
        object = itr.next();
    }

    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This still iterates under the hood, but doesn't involve manual iteration:

```java
set.stream().skip(set.size() / 2).findFirst().orElseThrow()
```